# Parse JSON API python

Tags: python, json, jsonparser

I have the following json:

```
    [{'errors': [],
  'configErrors': [],
  'summary': {'pullrequest': {'overall': {'count': 0,
     'lastUpdated': None,
     'stateCount': 0,
     'state': 'OPEN',
     'open': True},
    'byInstanceType': {}},
   'build': {'overall': {'count': 0,
     'lastUpdated': None,
     'failedBuildCount': 0,
     'successfulBuildCount': 0,
     'unknownBuildCount': 0},
    'byInstanceType': {}},
   'review': {'overall': {'count': 0,
     'lastUpdated': None,
     'stateCount': 0,
     'state': None,
     'dueDate': None,
     'overDue': False,
     'completed': False},
    'byInstanceType': {}},
   'deployment-environment': {'overall': {'count': 0,
     'lastUpdated': None,
     'topEnvironments': [],
     'showProjects': False,
     'successfulCount': 0},
    'byInstanceType': {}},
   'repository': {'overall': {'count': 0, 'lastUpdated': None},
    'byInstanceType': {}},
   'branch': {'overall': {'count': 0, 'lastUpdated': None},
    'byInstanceType': {}}}}
```

I need to retrieve value count.
I've tried with a loop for:

```
for item in json['summary']['pullreqest']['overall']:
     value = item['count']
```

but I have an error *must be integers or slices, not str* .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The json looks like an array, I fixed a typo (pulrequest) and simplified the retrieval of the item.

```
item = json[0]['summary']['pullrequest']['overall']
print(item)
value = item['count']
print(value)
```

When you loop through json[0]['summary']... what you are doing is taking the **keys**, but not the tuples, so you could not do item['count'].

All in all you are working with a Python dictionary and are bound by its rules.

Comment: @inspiredd Is that the whole JSON? Now that I look at it it's not valid.

Comment: I've added the whole JSON.

Comment: @inspiredd fixed my answer, is a bit different but I hope you find it useful. Also your new JSON is still missing the "]" at the end, just in case!

Comment: thanks a lot. I had 'key error 0' but I deleted 0 and it works perfect.